# Threads stopped but still running with false boolean value(Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

So the program I wrote is as follows:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class JustAClass{

    private volatile static boolean tof=true;

    private static void stop(){
        tof=false;
    }

    private static BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(10);

    private static void producer() throws InterruptedException{
        while(tof){
            Random random = new Random();
            queue.put(random.nextInt(100));
            System.out.println("........");
        }
    }
    private static void consumer() throws InterruptedException{
        while(tof){
        Random random = new Random();
            Thread.sleep(100);
            if(random.nextInt(10)==0){
                Integer value = queue.take();

                System.out.println("Value taken: "+value+"; Queue size: "+queue.size());
            }
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Press Enter to terminate");

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    producer();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    consumer();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        scanner.nextLine();
        stop();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.out.println("Terminated");
    }
}
```

The console normally shows this:

```
Press Enter to terminate
........
........
........
........
........
........
........
........
........
........
........
Value taken: 58; Queue size: 10
Value taken: 53; Queue size: 9
........
Value taken: 9; Queue size: 9
........
```

The program has to terminate once I press Enter. Though the outputs stop, the message "Terminated" doesn't appear. This must mean the threads must still be running. Where did I go wrong?
Plus, in some cases, the message "Terminated" appears and the threads stop. Why?

Comment: I don't see closing scanner on a way out

Comment: Your code is probably blocked on `queue.take()`

Comment: @Marvin it is not necessary here

Comment: @assylias I can't follow on the "blocked" part, though I'll play around with that part of the code a little more.

Comment: Adding to what @assylias said, your consumer only checks `tof` once after each `take()` call; but `take()` will never return if the queue is empty and the producer has stopped.  The solution to this problem is to _interrupt_ the thread.

Comment: Side question unrelated to the problem at hand: Why are you repeatedly creating *new* Random objects, a wasteful thing to do? Why not just create one Random object in the class, assign it to a static field, and simply use it repeatedly?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Simpler than that, just move them out of the while loop.

Comment: Thanks. Will keep that in mind for future codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the line here,

```
System.out.println(t1.getState()+" "+t2.getState()+" "+queue.size());
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
```

You will get the idea. The producer is waiting because the queue size is 10. For it to continue, the size must be less than 10. So, sometimes your condition

```
 if(random.nextInt(10)==0){
            Integer value = queue.take();

            System.out.println("Value taken: "+value+"; Queue size: "+queue.size());
        }
```

Might become true and it may go RUNNING mode again. For the rest of the time, it will keep waiting forever so will your main thread.

Answer (score 1):

this behavior is because how the `BlockingQueue` interface works.  before finish all the threads make sure that the drainTo method has been called, otherwise the `BlockingQueue` colud be waiting to return a value to a thread that no longer exists.  For more information of how BlockingQueue works go to  [BlockingQueue Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

A possilbe solution is: Go to the `consumer` method and after the while loop add this condition

```
if (!tof) queue.drainTo(new ArrayList<>());
```

This is how the conumer method looks like in order to finish the program

```
private static void consumer() throws InterruptedException{
    while(tof){
        Random random = new Random();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        if(random.nextInt(10)==0){
            Integer value = queue.take();

            System.out.println("Value taken: "+value+"; Queue size: "+queue.size());
        }
    }
    if (!tof) queue.drainTo(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Alternative 2:** the program wait until the queue is empty.  Go to consumer method, go to the while condition and validate if the queue is not empty `!queue.isEmpty()`

This is how alternative 2 looks like:

```
private static void consumer() throws InterruptedException{

        while(tof || !queue.isEmpty()){
            Random random = new Random();
            Thread.sleep(100);
            if(random.nextInt(10)==0){
                Integer value = queue.take();

                System.out.println("Value taken: "+value+"; Queue size: "+queue.size());
            }
        }
       // if (!tof) queue.drainTo(new ArrayList<>()); possible solution 1
    }
```

Comment: I used your first solution and it worked! Thank you!!